# HttpListener keep waiting forever if the localhost connection in closed from the browser

Tags: c#, google-oauth, httplistener

I am trying to integrate Google Auth in a native desktop application using a loopback approach by referring to Google [OAuthDesktopApp](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthDesktopApp/OAuthDesktopApp/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L84-L87). The problem that I am running into is httplistner keep waiting forever if the user has closed the tab in the browser. Is there a way by which listener can give a call back if the user has a closed browser tab? or any other approach which helps me to overcome this deadlock situation.

Comment: Show us your loopback approach. It's always a good idea to include some code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider creating a new form using the `WebBrowser` component: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8

Or if you're doing things in WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8

What I typically do when taking this approach is create a new form with a docked WebBrowser in it, which not only allows me to detect if the window is closed, I can also capture the redirect in those instances when the vendor won't allow a custom redirect URI.

The biggest disadvantage to this approach is that the built in browser is pretty awful; however, for a simple OAuth flow it is normally good enough.